# Qt: When nothing seems to update or repaint a tree

Tags: python, qt, tree, repaint

I have done a lot of reading on this and didn't find a solution. `update` and `repaint` did not seem to do anything for my tree. I did not want to rebuild it to get a simple repaint. I did not want to mess with the application, since it is not mine. I am just creating a widget for it.

I stumbled upon the answer posted and it seems to be working perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My widget's QTreeWidget is called "tree"....

```
def repaintAll(self):
    """ Refresh the paint on the entire tree """
    region = self.tree.childrenRegion()
    self.tree.setDirtyRegion(region)
```